# Is it possible to check whether a user is logged in to my website while sending request from another website using cookies/browser localstorage?

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a web application through which user can bookmark pages and can find them all collectively on my website. Whenever user want to bookmark any page he/she will just send a response to our server which will contain the url of the website. But if user is not logged in through our website, he/she will be redirected to our website login page. Now, "how would I check if any user is logged in to my website or not" or "when user is on different domain then how can we check for user's login status on our website"? I am working with django rest framework and javascript.

Comment: not entirely sure I understand your question. Are you asking if a user logs in on one device whether you can check if he's already logged in on another device? Or are you trying to make a thing similar to the facebook like button that can be placed on multiple websites?

Comment: No. When user click on the button to bookmark the page he is currently in a function is called. That function doesn't have any information of logged in user. Now how I check if user any user is logged in or not?

Comment: so it's like the facebook like button? the button is not on your website?

Comment: the button is the icon we have on our bookmark bar. On clicking that button javascript function is called.

Comment: A javascript XHR request will send the cookie of the domain to which the request is sent (your domain), so if the user is logged in, you will just see the regular session cookie (`request.user.is_authenticated() == True`). You shouldn't need to do anything different.

Comment: And if you want to know whether the user is logged inside your javascript, then you will need to make an XHR request to your website just to check the login status (you can create a special view for that). The session cookie will be sent and passed on that your django app can send back the login status.